# HTML Include Script Backwards

Tags: javascript, html

I know that one can include JS in their HTML files with a `<script src=""></script>` include, but can you specify it to load in the script `src` backwards (reading line by line bottom to top instead of top to bottom)? I would not like to include the script `src` with any inline JS or anything like that: it needs to be simply included in (but from bottom to top instead of top to bottom). Further, I understand I could just flip the script around so that loading it top to bottom isn't an issue, but I would like to know if there is any way I could simply load from bottom to top.

For example, here's a `test.js` file:

```js
alert("line 1!");
alert("line 2!");
alert("line 3!");
```

And if I include it in a `test.html` file, I could do this in the `<head></head>` or `<body></body>`:

```html
<script src="test.js"></script> <!-- Assuming They are in the same directory -->
```

Now when this `test.js` gets included, it is (as far as I am aware) going to read `test.js` from top to bottom, so `alert("line 1!")` will run before `alert("line 3!")`. And, if let's say line 1 in `test.js` is invalid, then the whole script stops getting included. I am wondering if I can do a `<script src="test.js"></script>` include where line 3 (the last line) gets read first (so `alert("line 3!")`) and the first line gets read last (`alert("line 1!")`). I am doing a cyber security challenge and I know that the top of the file I am trying to include is not valid JS, but the bottom is, so theoretically if I can include it from bottom to top I could get my JS to execute before it throws an error.

Comment: You could have the src point to a server script that reads a file backwards and returns that.

Comment: `src="backwards.php?file=filename.js"`

Comment: Why would you have a script written backwards?

Comment: @Barmar I am doing a cyber security challenge and would like to include the file backwards since the only valid JS in the file is at the bottom. I can't use `backwards.php` because the include has to be from the host server's domain (as defined by the CSP) and I can only upload an image. So I am uploaded a malicious image that has valid JS at the bottom of it, but including it causes an error because it is trying to read it from top to bottom.

Comment: Code is read from top to bottom left to right. It wouldn't make sense to read it backwards. The code won't work, as variables would become `undefined` in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that executes the script contents backward by sending an AJAX request to the target URL, splitting the response by a newline, reversing the resulting array, join into a string then use `eval`.

Something like this:

```js
function loadScriptBackwards(url) {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      eval(this.responseText.split("\n").reverse().join('\n'))
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: That will only work if each line is a complete statement. You should reverse the lines, join it back into a string, then eval that.

Comment: @Barmar True. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Spectric That is awsome! Thank you! But I cannot use any inline JS, it needs to be a script include of some sort.

Comment: This might not work in his challenge because his web page won't be in the same domain as the script file, so this will be blocked by CORS.

Comment: @Bob No, there's nothing built-in that will read a script backwards.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I am going to mark this as the answer but I technically can't use it.

Comment: @Barmar Is there a way to simply ignore errors in the JS file when including it with `<script src=>`?

Comment: @Bob I'm pretty sure there isn't.